# permission to access piwik.woff, broken fonts in Piwik 3

Tags: apache, matomo, woff

I'm hosting Piwik on an Ubuntu server with the whole LAMP stack. After upgrading to Piwik 3 the font stopped working.

I get this 403 error:

> You don't have permission to access /piwik/plugins/Morpheus/fonts/piwik.woff on this server.

I found [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/piwik/piwik/issues/8691) but I don't see what I should do.
I also tried adding mime types to `/etc/apache2/mods-available/mime.conf` but didn't really help either.

Permissions looked fine to me as well.

Answer (score 0):

I found the culprit: `plugins/.htaccess` contained

```
# Allow to serve static files which are safe
<Files ~ "\.(gif|ico|jpg|png|svg|js|css|htm|html|swf|mp3|mp4|wav|ogg|avi|ttf)$">
```

It looks as if this `plugins/.htaccess` was left over from an older version of Piwik, but I'm not sure about this.  I don't see `plugins/.htaccess` in [Piwik on GitHub](https://github.com/piwik/piwik/tree/3.x-dev/plugins).

Anyway, my solution is to add `woff` to the list of safe static files:

```
# Allow to serve static files which are safe
<Files ~ "\.(gif|ico|jpg|png|svg|js|css|htm|html|swf|mp3|mp4|wav|ogg|avi|ttf|woff)$">
```